# Code working in Codepen but not in Prepros?

Tags: css, stylus, prepros

I have some CSS Stylus code which compiles perfectly on CodePen:

```
for i in (1..3)
  $keyframe-name = (name + i)
    @keyframes {$keyframe-name} 
      0% 
        height 0
      75% 
        height 10px
      100%
```

However, when I compile in Prepros I get the following error;

```
css/style.styl:3
   1| 
   2| for i in (1..3)
 > 3|   $keyframe-name = (name + i)
   4|     @keyframes {$keyframe-name} 
   5|       0% 
   6|         height 0

cannot coerce 1 to ident
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepros just using an older version of Stylus. Codepen — 0.47.1, Prepros — 0.46.3.

Comment: Codepen — http://codepen.io/versions, Prepros — https://github.com/Subash/Prepros/blob/master/application/package.json

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I figured out a workaround to get it working in Prepros:

```
for i in (1..3)

    $keyframe-name = "name" + i + ""

        @keyframes $keyframe-name
            0% 
                height 0
            75% 
                height 10px
            100%
```

Don't know why there's a difference though.